# Odoo form button to save record

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to create a button in Odoo sass-14 that simply saves the record. I don't want the button to do anything else, just save the record. If I implement the button this way:

```
<button string="Save" class="btn-primary"/>
```

This record saves, but I get an error in the UI that says:

```
https://my-server.odoo.com/web/content/513-eca963c/web.assets_backend.js:2303
Traceback:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fail' of undefined
    at Class.on_confirmed (https://my-server.odoo.com/web/content/513-eca963c/web.assets_backend.js:2303:919)
    at exec_action (https://my-server.odoo.com/web/content/513-eca963c/web.assets_backend.js:2303:522)
    at https://my-server.odoo.com/web/content/490-ff226a6/web.assets_common.js:547:681
    at fire (https://my-server.odoo.com/web/content/490-ff226a6/web.assets_common.js:541:299)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://my-server.odoo.com/web/content/490-ff226a6/web.assets_common.js:546:198)
    at https://my-server.odoo.com/web/content/490-ff226a6/web.assets_common.js:547:874
    at fire (https://my-server.odoo.com/web/content/490-ff226a6/web.assets_common.js:541:299)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://my-server.odoo.com/web/content/490-ff226a6/web.assets_common.js:546:198)
    at deferred.(anonymous function) (https://my-server.odoo.com/web/content/490-ff226a6/web.assets_common.js:548:56)
    at fire (https://my-server.odoo.com/web/content/490-ff226a6/web.assets_common.js:541:299)
```

Is it possible to create a button that simply saves the record?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this button?

```
<button type="object" name="write" string="Save" class="btn-primary"/>
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I guess it technically works, but I didn't love this solution because it still calls an additional method. Clicking any button automatically saves the record. Clicking the button you show means it's saved, and then write is called a second time. I would prefer to just click the button, which saves the record, and then does nothing else. Is that possible?